# AutoCompleteTextView & Async class

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I am a rookie in the Android world and I built up a small training SW based on the 2.1 Google API.

At that time I did not know yet about main thread and worker threads, so I put all my code in the main thread.

Since, I fixed it with async classes for my netwkork access to fit the  4.0 Google API.

Ok, but one last thing bothers me and I just can not find any clues.

It is about an *AutoCompleteTextView* on a field *ville* ("town" in french).

---

**BEFORE (2.1):**

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{
String result = null;
InputStream is = null;
List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (ville.enoughToFilter())
    {
        is = connexionHttp(BASE_URL + "ville.php?ville=" + ville.getText());
        result = lectureData(is);

        try
        {           
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
                   json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);  
                   r.add(json_data.getString("VILLE"));
                   a_idVil.add(json_data.getString("CLEF_VILLE"));      
            }
            ville.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,r));
            ville.setOnItemSelectedListener(new villeListener());

        }
        catch(JSONException e1)
        {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("***** TestActivity/onTextChanged: JSONException *****", "--"+e1.toString()+"--");
        } 
        catch(ParseException e1) 
        {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e1.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("***** TestActivity/onTextChanged: ParseException *****", "--"+e1.toString()+"--");
        }
    }
}
public class villeListener implements OnItemSelectedListener 
{
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long row) 
    {
        villePosition = pos;    
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)  {   }
}
```

runs 100% perfect:

-> after the 4th caracters, the query runs on MySql to find all the towns beginning with the 4 given letters, and displays the selection list to select the right one: OK

-> the listener give the index of the choosen town: OK

---

**AFTER (4.0)**

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{           
if (ville.enoughToFilter())
{           
    new RemplirVille().execute(BASE_URL + "ville.php?ville=" + ville.getText());
    Log.d("***********","AVANT");  
    ville.setOnItemSelectedListener(new villeListener());
    Log.d("***********","APRES");           
}

}
public class villeListener implements OnItemSelectedListener 
{
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos, long row) 
{
    villePosition = pos;
    Log.d("*************9999999", "1111111111");
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)  {   }
}

class RemplirVille extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<String>>
{
Integer errorMsgId;
String  errorMsgParam;

protected List<String> doInBackground(String... param)
{
    List<String> listeAffichageVille = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    try 
    {
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();      
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(param[0]);
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);     
             if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < 400) 
             {
                  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                  String entityStr = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                  JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(entityStr);

                  for(int i=0;i<json_array.length();i++) 
                  {
                      JSONObject json_ligne = json_array.getJSONObject(i);                            
                      listeAffichageVille.add(json_ligne.getString("VILLE"));
                      a_idVil.add(json_ligne.getString("CLEF_VILLE"));
                  }
            } 
            else 
            {
                Log.d("***** TestActivity/ASYNC RemplirVille: EXCEPTION http error *****", "--"+response.getStatusLine().toString()+"--"); 
                this.errorMsgId = R.string.http_site_error;
                listeAffichageVille = null;
            }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
            Log.d("***** TestActivity/ASYNC RemplirVille: EXCEPTION decode error *****", "--"+ex.toString()+"--");
            this.errorMsgId = R.string.http_decode_error;
            this.errorMsgParam = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
            listeAffichageVille = null;
    }
    return listeAffichageVille;
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(String... item) {   }
protected void onPreExecute(List<String> list)  {   }
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> list)     
{               
    if (list == null)
    {
          if (this.errorMsgId != null) 
          {
              String msg = TestActivity.this.getString(this.errorMsgId);
              Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }    
    }
    else            
    {
        ville.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(TestActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,list));
    }
}   
}
```

runs with troubles:

-> you have to put in (enoughToFilter + 1) caractères to diplay the list of the towns: BAD

-> the listener is even not run anymore: BAD

---

In fact **enoughToFilter** works well, it launches the RemplirVille class which runs ok except that it does not displays the list!

But, if you put in 1 more caracter:
->  **enoughToFilter** still working well
-> RemplirVille brings the data one more time.... but this time the selection list displays well.

Any idea about that topic?
I guess it is a context problem, but even with a GetApplicationCOntext I just can not get it.

Thanks.

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Answer (score 2):

Calling `AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter()` does not automatically show the dropdown, but you can force the dropdown to be shown with `AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown()`.

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> list){
    //...
    ville.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(TestActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,list));
    if(ville.isInputMethodTarget()){
        ville.showDropDown();
    }
    //...
}
```

Without this, the dropdown was not shown until the next character was typed, which gave the (enoughToFilter + 1) problem.